# Problems with data icons using jquery mobile on retina display

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

I've folowing problems using jquery mobile and testing the app on a retina display.
I'm using the current release candidate of the jquerymobile framework and miss the icons of backbuttons list views etc (like on the image attached).
With an iPhone 3GS with same iOS version it works correct

Does anyone of you know a fix solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

This image show whats missing.
http://playground.appstack.io/example.png

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run Media Queries for Retina displays. Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/mediahelpers.html

**Running Media Queries**

> ```
> jQuery Mobile provides a function that allows you to test whether a particular
> ```
>
> CSS Media Query applies. Simple call $.mobile.media() and
>   pass a media type or query. If the browser supports that type or
>   query, and it currently applies, the function will return true. If
>   not, it'll return false.

```
//test for screen media type
$.mobile.media("screen");

//test  a min-width media query
$.mobile.media("screen and (min-width: 480px)");

//test for iOS retina display
$.mobile.media("screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)");
```